# NativeScript platform add error

Tags: telerik, nativescript

I am trying to add the android platform to my  NativeScript project.  When I run tns platform add android I get the following error: **Package name must look like: com.company.Name**

Here is my environment:
tns version 2.0.0, 
node version 4.4.3, 
tns doctor returns **No issues were detected**

Package name in project.json:  **com.mycompany.myproject**

The error message has the Name with capital N.  However if I try to use Myproject, the regex (^[^A-Z] + $) applied to the name does not validate.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the *AndroidManifest.xml* located in `app/App_Resources/Android` and putting your package name there under the `<manifest>` tag. Then run `tns build android` and see what happens. This should run just fine. If not, you might try getting a new app and see if something isn't borked on that project elsewhere causing this issue to bubble up. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I ended up creating a blank app and following the convention there.  My environment was not set properly as well.  After all this was corrected, everything runs well now.